# How to get items from second, third, ... pages on amazon

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-product-api

Hey I came to the problem where parsing products from amazon page using Product Advertising API you reach ceiling... I noticed that I can parse only first 50 products maximum... And if I want to parse products from 5th page I can't.. Is there another approach to get wanted products??

Comment: Does paging the API not work ?

Comment: @john in amazon documentation using ItemPage it's value can be 1 to 10 (1 to 5 when search index is All). Mostly I need search index "All" so for now I can get max 50 products...

Comment: The [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingandSortingThroughResults.html#PagingThroughResults) says you can't do that and you need to search for something more exact to get more.